# Bash - how to print the number of times a value in a column occurs at the end of the row

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a tab delimited file...

```
123 1:2334523   yes
127 1:332443    yes
113 1:332443    no
115 1:55434     no
115 1:55434     no
115 1:55434     yes
```

I would like to count the number of times the value in column 2 appears in column 2 and then print it to the the end of the row like...

```
123 1:2334523   yes 1
127 1:332443    yes 2
113 1:332443    no  2
115 1:55434     no  3
115 1:55434     no  3   
115 1:55434     yes 3
```

So in column 2 1:332443 appears twice and 1:55434 appears 3 times.

I assume this should be relatively easy in Awk or sed but have not managed to figure it out.

Comment: Which value you mean?

Comment: all values. will edit to make clearer

Comment: Which appears twice? Where `1:332443` appears  twice in col2?

Comment: yes. so in the example there are 6 values in column 2, 1:2334523 appears once, 1:332443 appears twice and 1:55434 appears 3 times. this counting should be independent of whatever values are in columns 1 and 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { ++ctr[$2]; next } { print $0 "\t" ctr[$2]; }' filename filename
```

Because we need to know the counters before printing, we need two passes over the file, that's why `filename` is mentioned twice. The awk code then is:

```
NR == FNR {    # if the record number is the same as the record number in the
               # current file (that is: in the first pass)
  ++ctr[$2]    # count how often field 2 showed up
  next         # don't do anything else for the first pass
}
{              # then in the second pass:
  print $0 "\t" ctr[$2];   # print the line, a tab, and the counter.
}
```

Comment: Excellent works perfectly. I would not have figured at passing over the same file twice

Comment: You can shorten it some by change  `filename filename` to  `filename{,}` when reading file twice.

Comment: That's bash-specific, but yes, you could do that. And the question is tagged "bash," I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an  `awk` that read the file just once:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0;b[$2]++;c[NR]=$2} END {for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) print a[i]"\t"b[c[i]]}' file
123 1:2334523   yes     1
127 1:332443    yes     2
113 1:332443    no      2
115 1:55434     no      3
115 1:55434     no      3
115 1:55434     yes     3
```

This store all the data inn to an array `a`. Count the number of fields `2` in array `b`, then store index inn array `c`.
At then end, do print out the arrays.